# Which basename i am going to use as prefix in i.landsat8.swlst in GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0, add-ons

I want to use i.landsat8.swlst add-on in GRASS GIS to calculate LST from Landsat8 data for my study area.

In the following command:

```
i.landsat8.swlst mtl=MTL prefix=B landcover=FROM_GLC -n
```

​Which Basename i am going to provide as prefix for landsat8 data?

Comment: Say, the the name of of the Landsat8 bands i imported in GRASS GIS is as LC81470372015290LGN00_B2, and i am supported to use prefix=the prefix of the band names imported in GRASS GIS data base. I don't know what is the basename in above imported band.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this query.

Say, we are going to calculate LST for Landsat8 scene (LC81470372015290LGN00_B2), 
The Basename we are going to use for prefix in above mentioned command is:

LC81470372015290LGN00_B

(Exclude the band number rest will be your Basename)